# How to create two tables in single plot using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create multiple tables in a single plot using plotly and wondering how to do it.

I have a dataset like this:

```py
data_US = [['Country', 'Year', 'Population'],
           ['United States', 2000, 282200000],
           ['United States', 2005, 295500000],
           ['United States', 2010, 309000000]
          ]

data_Canada= [['Country', 'Year', 'Population'],
              ['Canada', 2000, 27790000],
              ['Canada', 2005, 32310000],
              ['Canada', 2010, 34000000]]
```

How can we show these datasets in a single plot?

Here is my attempt:

```py
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly import tools
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

def create_two_tables(lst1,lst2):
    table1 = ff.create_table(lst1)
    table2 = ff.create_table(lst2)

    fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2,
                          cols=1,
                          print_grid=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.085,
                          subplot_titles=('US population', 'Canada population')
    )

    fig.append_trace(table1['data'][0], 1, 1)
    fig.append_trace(table2['data'][0], 2, 1)

    fig['layout']['xaxis1']= dict(fig['layout']['xaxis1'].to_plotly_json(),
                                  **table1['layout']['xaxis'].to_plotly_json())
    fig['layout']['yaxis1']= dict(fig['layout']['yaxis1'].to_plotly_json(),
                                  **table1['layout']['yaxis'].to_plotly_json())
    fig['layout']['xaxis2']= dict(fig['layout']['xaxis2'].to_plotly_json(),
                                  **table2['layout']['xaxis'].to_plotly_json())
    fig['layout']['yaxis2']= dict(fig['layout']['yaxis2'].to_plotly_json(),
                                  **table2['layout']['yaxis'].to_plotly_json())

    for k in range(len(table2['layout']['annotations'])):
            table2['layout']['annotations'][k].update(xref='x2', yref='y2')

    fig['layout']['annotations'].extend(
        table1['layout']['annotations']+table2['layout']['annotations']) 

    fig['layout'].update(width=800, height=600, margin=dict(t=100, l=50, r=50, b=50))

    iplot(fig, filename='two_tables.html')

# Create two data and make a table
data_US = [['Country', 'Year', 'Population'],
           ['United States', 2000, 282200000],
           ['United States', 2005, 295500000],
           ['United States', 2010, 309000000]
          ]

data_Canada= [['Country', 'Year', 'Population'],
              ['Canada', 2000, 27790000],
              ['Canada', 2005, 32310000],
              ['Canada', 2010, 34000000]]

create_two_tables(data_US,data_Canada)
```

But I am getting TYPE ERROR.
This code was working before the update of plotly (the thery was no `.to_plotly_json()` to above four lines) and due to some API changes the code is not working now.

How to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

this might feel odd solution but try to find about API changes or place question here:
https://community.plot.ly/
Good luck!